# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Network Engineering's [second moderator election](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Ron Maupin]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6337301126840320/0).

Comment: Congratulations, @RonMaupin!

Comment: @TeunVink, thank you. You know, of course, I will be leaning on you heavily until I learn. :)

Comment: @RonMaupin Congrats!

Comment: @RonMaupin no problem at all, I did the same with Ylearn and Craig ;-)